# ZooKeeper - clients co-ordination after one or more client lose connection with ZooKeeper

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, orchestration

I've two processes running in their respective JVMs (say node A and B). They connect to a single ZooKeeper server to co-ordinate task execution. Either one of the nodes (A or B) should execute a `scheduled task (freq 1 minute)` at a time, not both. Also, if A fails, then B should take over to execute the task at next scheduled time.

**Following is the problem**:

Node A wins the race and creates some ephemeral node on ZooKeeper to indicate that it has started executing the task.Once A starts executing the task, it lost the connection with ZooKeeper and hence ZooKeeper deletes the ephemeral node after some time. Because of unexpected bigger size of data, the execution went past 1 minute boundary. Now when B wakes up, it wouldn't see any ephemeral node which A had created earlier. In the absence of that node, B considers no other node is executing the task and it also starts executing the task in parallel with `disconnected` A, which is wrong. Either A or B should run the task.

**I prefer A to complete the started task even when it is not connected to ZooKeeper and B NOT running in parallel till A finishes the task.**

I'm using `org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient` client library. Is there any solution apart from custom `heartbeat` mechanism?

Comment: I think your solution should depend on whether you prefer A to complete the started task or rather to make sure that B is able to run next time it starts.

Comment: @OlegKomarov You are right, I forgot to mention that. Adding it now in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to have a directory with all the current tasks being executed. When node A finishes executing the task T, node B already started executing task T. Now, what you can do is try to kill node B and commit all the changes produced by node A. This is a variation of the principle of speculative execution. You can either kill node B or discard all the changes done by this node if node A managed to perform the task successfully.

Comment: The problem is that the if B ran, then it would do a non-reversible changes to the system.
However, the approach could be useful in some other scenario. Upvoting for a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you set higher session timeout, ephemeral node created by B will not be deleted and B will not execute the task.

To be specific,

- if you know the maximum time a thread can take for executing a task, set that max time as session time out
- else decide the timeout based on average execution time, p-90 or some other heuristics

Comment: The downside would be that if the task executions were small, then B would also not run it for several (or till the session times out) next schedules.